# Test case failed in executing special palindromic strings program

Tags: java

- I am trying to solve hacker rank question for counting number of special palindrome strings contained within a string
- To be considered for Special palindrome strings, all the characters should be same, as well as all characters except middle one are the same
- Say for example, string = asasd, then palindromic strings are {a, s, a, s, d, asa, sas}
- In this program, two test cases are passed with strings asasd and aaaa respectively
- One test case failed for the string abcbaba
- I researched for checking second condition but I am struck with the execution
- can you guys help me to solve issue with your suggestions
- providing entire code below:

```or-tag-here
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int counter=0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt(); // read an integer from input stream.
        String s = scanner.next();
        char string_array[] = s.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
            for(int j=i; j<=s.length(); j++){
                if(i != j){
                    String s1 = s.substring(i,j);
                    String rev = "";
                    for(int z=0; z<s1.length(); z++){
                    rev = rev + s1.charAt(s1.length()-1-z);
                    }
                    //System.out.println("s1=" + s1 +  "rev=" + rev);
                    int count = s1.compareTo(rev);
                    if(count == 0){
                    counter++;
                }
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println(counter);
}
```

Comment: I checked your failing use case, it returns 11 palindrom  matches which are all correct: abcbaba -> a, b, c, b, a, b, a, aba, bab, bcb, abcba. Can you explain why you think you have an issue here?

Comment: The issue is that `abcba` is not a valid *special* palindrome, it is a *normal* palindrome. To re-phrase the rules for *special* palindrome, **all characters must be the same**, except that *middle character* of odd-length string can be different. E.g. `a`, `aa`, `aba`, `aaaa`, `aabaa`, `aaaaaa`, `aaabaaa`, `aaaaaaaa`, `aaaabaaaa` are *special*, but `abbba` is not, any string with a third, forth, fifth, ... character is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm did not contain a check for the special palindrome requirement for character equality. The following algorithm adds such a check:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int counter=0;
        String s = "abcbaba";
        char string_array[] = s.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
            for(int j=i; j<=s.length(); j++){
                if(i != j){
                    String s1 = s.substring(i,j);
                    String rev = "";
                    char complianceChar = s1.charAt(0);
                    boolean isSpecialPalindrom = true;
                    boolean isLengthEven = s1.length()%2==0;
                    for(int z=0; z<s1.length(); z++) {
                        char c = s1.charAt(s1.length()-1-z);
                        rev = rev + c;
                        boolean isMiddleChar = (z == (s1.length()-1)/2);
                        if(isSpecialPalindrom && (isLengthEven || !isMiddleChar)) {
                            isSpecialPalindrom = (c == complianceChar);
                        }
                    }
                    int count = s1.compareTo(rev);
                    if(count == 0 && isSpecialPalindrom){
                        System.out.println(rev);
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
a
b
bcb
c
b
bab
a
aba
b
a
10
```